# How to compare one column to a series of related dummy variables without a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have working R code, but it is inelegant and inefficient. I am wondering if there is a better way: i.e. how can I vectorize this process and/or reduce the computing time?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
    visited_a = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
    visited_b = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
    visited_c = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
    purchased = c("b", "b", "c", "a")
)
```

My data.table has dummy indicators for whether a consumer visited a store in 2017. So `visited_a = 0` means she did not visit store `a` in 2017 while `visited_b = 1` means she did visit store `b` in 2017. The data also list which store the consumer purchased from in 2018; all of these consumers made a purchase. Thus a consumer may or may not have visited the store (last year) that she purchased from (this year).

I want to add a variable `purchased_was_visited` to capture this. The solution would be:

```
dt$purchased_was_visited <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Here is my extraordinary inelegant code that sadly loops through the data.table one row at a time.  There must be a better way!

```
dt[ , purchased_was_visited := NA]
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
    brand <- dt[i, purchased]
    col <- paste0("visited_", brand)
    was_it <- dt[i, ..col]
    dt[i, purchased_was_visited := was_it]
}
```

Comment: This may be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), given that your code already works.  Requests for "a better way" are [a little too general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349516/2799941), in general, to be suitable for SO.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of Code Review.  I will update this question (whether it survives here or moves to Code Review) to specify what I mean by "better".

Comment: Re your edit, yeah, at least for R, "how do I not do this row-by-row?" is usually treated as on-topic here, and is usually relevant to [tag:performance]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use `get` by grouping on each row. One has to prepare the column name (based on `purchased`) which needs to be evaluated to check for past visit. Now, `get` function will provide desired result if evaluated for each row. Hence, we need to group on each row (e.g. `by=1:NROW(dt)`) :

```
library(data.table)

dt[,purchased_was_visited := get(paste("visited",purchased,sep="_")), by=1:NROW(dt)]

dt
#    visited_a visited_b visited_c purchased purchased_was_visited
# 1:         1         1         0         b                     1
# 2:         1         0         0         b                     0
# 3:         0         0         1         c                     1
# 4:         0         0         1         a                     0
```

Comment: I like how short this code is -- and I've never seen `NROW` used with `by` - clever! FWIW, my dataset has 35 "visited" columns and approx 40k rows, and your solution offered a speed improvement of 67x over my poor for-loop.

Answer (score 4):

I would give your consumers an ID column and store the data in two tables:

```
dt[, cid := .I]

# visits
vDT = melt(dt, id="cid", meas=patterns("visited"), variable.name = "store")[value == 1, !"value"]
vDT[, store := tstrsplit(store, "_")[[2]]]
vDT[, year := 2017L]

# choices
cDT = dt[, .(cid, year = 2018L, store = purchased)]
```

Then you can do a join to add the indicator column to cDT:

```
cDT[, v_before := vDT[.SD, on=.(cid, store, year < year), .N, by=.EACHI]$N]

   cid year store v_before
1:   1 2018     b        1
2:   2 2018     b        0
3:   3 2018     c        1
4:   4 2018     a        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do using base `apply` commands:

```
## get index of column names which are 1
vals <- apply(dt[,1:3], 1, function(x) which(x == 1))
vals <- lapply(vals, function(x) names(x))

# replace the string in column names before underscore
vals <- lapply(vals, function(x) gsub(pattern = '.*._',replacement = '',x = x))

# create the final column
dt[, purchased_was_visited := mapply(function(x,y) as.integer(x %in% y), purchased, vals)]

print(dt)

   visited_a visited_b visited_c purchased purchased_was_visited
1:         1         1         0         b                     1
2:         1         0         0         b                     0
3:         0         0         1         c                     1
4:         0         0         1         a                     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about its elegance but here is a "tidy" and efficient  `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

setDF(dt)

dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(
    check_a = if_else(visited_a == 1, if_else(purchased == "a", 1, 0), 0),
    check_b = if_else(visited_b == 1, if_else(purchased == "b", 1, 0), 0),
    check_c = if_else(visited_c == 1, if_else(purchased == "c", 1, 0), 0),
    purchased_was_visited = check_a + check_b + check_c
  ) %>%
  select(-c(5:7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea - make your values in "purchased" match the names you give to the visited columns. This way "purchased" can be used to give you a direct lookup of the values needed. Here, I have renamed 'visited_a' to just 'a', etc. This could also be done programmatically, as you and the some others have done, but perhaps designing for your data and data table in advance for usability is a tidier option.

```
dt <- data.frame(
    a = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
    b = c(1, 0, 0, 0),
    c = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
    purchased = c("b", "b", "c", "a")
    )

dt$purchased_was_visited <- 
     sapply(row.names(dt), function(i) {(dt[i, dt[i, 'purchased']])})

dt

#   a b c purchased purchased_was_visited
# 1 1 1 0         b                     1
# 2 1 0 0         b                     0
# 3 0 0 1         c                     1
# 4 0 0 1         a                     0
```

Sorry, I used a data.frame not a data.table, but the same principle applies.